# Script - How to add UV map for each object in scene?

Tags: python, scripting, uv

I need a script which will add a second UVmap with "map1" name for all my objects in scene.

I tried :

```
import bpy
for obj in bpy.context.visible_objects:
    uvt = obj.data.uv_textures
    for m in uvt:
            obj.data.uv_textures.new("map1")
```

But this does not work. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add UV to all mesh objects in scene**

Note: for 2.8x replace `uv_textures` with `uv_layers` and add (name="yourUVname") in .new()

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
# all meshes on mesh objects in scene
meshes = [o.data for o in scene.objects
        if o.type == 'MESH']
# add a new "map1" UV to each        
for m in meshes:
    m.uv_textures.new("map1")
```

Note could be done in list comprehension with

```
uvs = [o.data.uv_textures.new("map1") for o in scene.objects
        if o.type == 'MESH']
```